# Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать эпитафию.Печаль и боль нам не излить слезами.Всегда вы здесь всегда вы с нами

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно написать эпитафию?
Печаль и боль нам не излить слезами.Всегда вы здесь всегда вы с нами.

Comment: Надо поставить одну запятую, это бессоюзное сложное предложение: Печаль и боль нам не излить слезами. Всегда вы здесь,  всегда вы с нами.

Comment: Печаль и боль нам не излить слезами. Всегда вы здесь, всегда мы с вами. (Иначе — повтор мысли, что не возбраняется).